# Redirection of subdirectory to parent subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following file structure

```
- example.com
- - app
- - - index.html
- - api
- - - web
- - - - index.php
```

How can I redirect my domain local.example.com to app/* and local.example.com/api/ to api/web* ?

this one does it all, expects it redirects to /api/ instead of /api/web.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:api|app)/)(.*)$ /app/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in root .htaccess (1 level above `app` directory):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:api|app)(/(?!web).*)?$ /app$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! if I want it to make this condition even in prod enviorement, can I just delete the ^local\. ?

Comment: Yes you can delete that condition to make it work in prod also.